# "command not found: create-react-app" error when trying to create a react app

Tags: reactjs, npx

I have started learning React JS. When I try running the command `npx create-react-app myapp`, I get this error:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Sameha` 
`command not found: create-react-app`

Why is this happening? I have node version 14.17.5 installed.

Comment: are you running cmd with admin privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to run it locally with npm instead:**

`npm install -g create-react-app`

**Then**

`npm create-react-app myapp`

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried this command and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

it is a permission error. All you need to do is open `Command Prompt` as administrator, and run the same command again. It should hopefully solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are uninstall the node and then reinstall the latest version,  then it will be worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**npm create-react-app my-app** doesn't work any more.
Try  **npx create-react-app my-app**